# How to form an URL in Background thread before using it with an API?

Tags: java, android, api, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am working with an API for the first time.

My need is that I need to form an URL with certain parameters out of which one parameter cannot be formed in the Main UI thread and has to be formed in the Background thread.

I am planning to use to volley library to post the GET request.

I am using the [Needle](https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/needle) library which helps in running background tasks. This is What I have tried till now.

```
Needle.onBackgroundThread().execute(new UiRelatedTask<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doWork() {

                return url = GetUrl();
            }

            @Override
            protected void thenDoUiRelatedWork(String result1) {
                Log.e("JSON", url);
                final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                        new Response.Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Object response) {
                                Log.e("JSON", response.toString());
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("JSON", error.toString());
                    }
                });
                RequestQueue queue = VolleyController.getInstance(Activity.this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
                queue.start();
                queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });
```

But the Main problem is that After the `GetUrl()` method immediately the `thenDoUiRelatedWork` method is called hence the request is made using an Invalid URL as the URL will still be loading in the background and then when the loading of the URL is over I am logging the URL Which is right.

I cannot use an AysncTask as my app is already using three AsyncTaks and additionally two more could be activated by the user based on the feature he is using. And also the API request has to be done in various places (3-4 places) hence using an AsyncTask will not be suitable.

Can anyone help me to first form the URL fully in the Background and the use volley to post the GET request.

Comment: You can use an inf loop before creating `jsonObjectRequest ` and wait for valid URL. Something like this `while(url != null){;}` (btw it is not a good solution at all.)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Will use this solution in the last if I am not able to settle with any other solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your GetUrl function? According to the documentation, thenDoUiRelatedWork is called after finishing execution of doWork.

If you end up using @Math10 approach, it would be better to use infinite loop in doWork function, as that runs in background, instead of thenDoUiRelatedWork which will run on Main thread.

https://zsoltsafrany.github.io/needle/

Comment: Let me know if you use inf loop as solution, I will add it as answer.

Comment: @Math10 OK. Will surely do that.